# Procmail script creates files with unexpected read/write permissions

Tags: linux, permissions, procmail

Running under CentOS 6.5, I have a procmail recipe that invokes a Perl script that processes mail addressed to reguser and writes a file like:

```
my $text = "Text generated from incoming mail";
my $filename = "test.txt";
open(FILE, ">" . $filename) or die "Can't open file $filename";
print FILE $text;
close FILE;
```

When this file is created when the script is run from Procmail, only root has read/write permissions like

```
-rw------- 1 regusr regusr     33 Sep 12 22:40 test.txt
```

These permissions seem a bit arbitrary.  When my Perl script is run from the command line as regusr, I get permissions like:

```
 -rw-rw-r-- 1 regusr regusr    33 Sep 14 14:22 test.txt
```

Why is there a difference?

Comment: Probably, `procmail` changes the default `UMASK`. Try to set `UMASK` explicitly in your procmailrc file using `UMASK=077` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Ahh UMASK ...  I had not thought of that.  In .procmailrc UMASK=077 did not have any effect, but UMASK=003 seemed to have the desired effect, specifically masking write and execute for other users.  I just found in the Procmail docs "If not specified, the umask defaults to 077" http://pm-doc.sourceforge.net/doc/#variable_umask

Comment: Please post that as an answer so that this question no longer shows up as unresolved.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ahh UMASK ... I had not thought of that. In .procmailrc UMASK=077 did not have any effect, but UMASK=003 seemed to have the desired effect, specifically masking write and execute for other users. I just found in the Procmail docs "If not specified, the umask defaults to 077" pm-doc.sourceforge.net/doc/#variable_umask